# Showing arrows crossing over or under other arrows in xy-pic without knots

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I have an xymatrix in which two arrows cross each other, say

```
\xymatrix{ \ar[dr] &  \\ \ar[ur] & }
```

and I would like one arrow to cross over the other. I also want to to be able to do this without using knots; the reason is that I want to draw some diagrams where the arrows just intersect and some diagrams where they don't, and I'd prefer that they have a uniform look to them.

There is an example of how to do this in the [xy-pic user's guide](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/xy/doc/xyguide.pdf), but 1) I don't quite understand it, and 2) it seems to require that I thread a single arrow through multiple entries. I don't want to have to do that; I really just want two arrows, one of which crosses over the other.

I tried to give the "under" arrow an empty label, but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not so hard.

Dig a hole:

```
\xymatrix{ \ar[dr]|\hole &  \\ \ar[ur] & }
```

Calculate the intersection point and dig a hole:

```
\xymatrix{ \ar[drr]|!{[d];[r]}\hole & & \\ \ar[ur] & & }
```

[image]

Comment: @Stefan: Then use `\xymatrix{ \ar[drr]|!{[d];[r]}\hole & & \\ \ar[ur] & & }`

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment regarding manual adjustment right before you added yours. It's good to have a `|!{...}` notation example here now.

Comment: Great, thanks! Quick follow-up question: the diagonal arrows are showing up weirdly aliased in my PDF reader (Foxit). Is this a problem with my reader or should I be tweaking a TeX setting or what?

Comment: @Qiaochu: Try `\usepackage{xypdf}`.

Answer (score 4):

There's a general trick, no matter if xy-pic or let's say TikZ is used. It also works with bent arrows, naturally.

1. Draw the arrow which shall cross below
2. Draw the arrow which shall cross above, but thick and in background color
3. Draw the arrow which shall cross above again, but normally

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvips,all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ \ar[dr]& \\ \ar@*{[|(6)][white]}[ur]\ar[ur] & }
\end{document}
```

For line styles and color a capable driver is required. I used dvips.

[image]

Comment: In TikZ, it's OK. However, I don't think it is needed in Xy-pic.

Comment: @Leo: this way I don't need to take care where to put an empty break by `\hole`, such as in complex drawings with many arrows crossing, possibly even bent.

Comment: That's still not necessary. See "Exercise 6" of `xyguide`.

Comment: @Leo: I see what you mean, using the crossing notation.