# xypic putting a hole when two arrows cross

Tags: xy-pic

I am trying to draw the following figure in trying to typeset the lattice
diagram of the semidihedral group or order 16. Here is my tex code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}


\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    \xymatrix{
&&&& G \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d] \ar@{-}[dr]   \\
&&& A \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dr]& B  \ar@{-}[d]&C \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}
[dr] \\
          &&D \ar@{-}[dll] \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[drr] & E \ar@{-}[dl]|!{[dl];[l]}\hole \ar@{-}[d] \ar@{-}[dr] & F \ar@{-}[d] & H & I    \\
         J \ar@{-}[drrrr] &K \ar@{-}[drrr]&L \ar@{-}[drr]& M \ar@{-}[dr]& N \ar@{-}[d] \\
         &&&& F}
\end{displaymath}



\end{document}
```

I want EL to have a hole when it crosses DN and I want EM to have a hole when it
crosses DN. How do I achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited your code by using the `{}` button :)

Comment: Thanks so much. I was wondering how to do this. Can you help me?.

Comment: As there are no nodes at the crossing point, the method from the xyguide can not be used. Please look at this similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10361/showing-arrows-crossing-over-or-under-other-arrows-in-xy-pic-without-knots

Comment: Yes, I read this. But I don't quite understand how to compute the point of intersection?.

Comment: As I understand it `{[d];[r]}` is the intersection line.

Comment: Just another side-remark: If you just want the usual straight line you don’t need to add `@{-}` because that is the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the method from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10365/15616 to the gap in *DN*. I tried also to use the same for *EM*, but curiously that deleted the whole line up to the intersection point as well. So there I just used a gap in the middle.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xypic}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    \xymatrix{
        &&&& G \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d] \ar@{-}[dr]\\
        &&& A \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dr]
            & B \ar@{-}[d]&C \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[d]\ar@{-}[dr]\\
        && D \ar@{-}[dll] \ar@{-}[dl] \ar@{-}[drr]
            & E \ar@{-}[dl]|!{[l];[dr]}\hole \ar@{-}[d]|\hole \ar@{-}[dr]
            & F \ar@{-}[d] & H & I\\
        J \ar@{-}[drrrr]
            & K \ar@{-}[drrr]
            & L \ar@{-}[drr]
            & M \ar@{-}[dr]& N \ar@{-}[d]\\
            &&&& F}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

### Explanation:

This  uses the *intercept* calculation of xypics. Compare for example `⟨place⟩` of Figure 1 in [XY-pic Reference](http://web.math.ku.dk/%7Eholm/download/xyrefer.pdf) and point *3j* there. By using this in the context of an arrow (see Figure 14 `⟨labels⟩` and `⟨anchor⟩`) this calculates the intersection point of the line given by `{[l];[dr]}`, relative to the current node, and the current arrow.